# IPad On Screen (virtual keyboard) does not hide when using Logitech K380 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

It used to be that when I connected a Bluetooth external keyboard to my iPad the virtual keyboard would be hidden. Today I tried to use my new Logitech K380 external Bluetooth keyboard and the virtual keyboard remained on the screen. I was able to manually minimize the keyboard and still use the external keyboard but when I switch between apps the virtual keyboard is back up again. Has this functionality changed in recent updates?

iPad Pro 10.5" - iOS 12.1.1

Comment: Did you try restarting the iPad?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yes I did. No effect. The virtual keyboard is always visible when I switch to another app that has input even if the last time I used the app the virtual keyboard was hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m typing this on a Logitech K380 at this very moment and can confirm that the on-screen keyboard hides when connected.

I’m running iPadOS 13.3.1 so I would suggest upgrading to the latest OS for your device.